# Почему данный метод возвращает не массив, а undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "1111",
database: "crypto"
});
function get_date() {
con.connect(function () {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM btc", function (err, result, fields) {
        var array = [result.length];
        var string = JSON.stringify(result);
        var json = JSON.parse(string);
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (json[i].price != "null") {
                array.push(json[i].price)
            }
        }
        return array
    })
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В функции function get_date() нету return соответственно ничего не возвращает.

Comment: А как же строчка  return array

Comment: @НикитаПетров , `return array` находится в функции, которую вы передаёте в виде параметра при вызове метода `con.query()`, а не в функции `get_date`, и мне кажется что в данном примере вам лучше использовать `callback`,

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, напишите пожалуйста более развернутый ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Извините, но все же мне нужно не печатать информацию, а получить массив как отдельной переменной. Как бы мне обратится к анонимной фунции

Comment: @НикитаПетров, я не работаю с node.js, однако, судя по Вашему примеру вернуть данные Вы не можете поскольку `con.query()`, не возвращает данные, а принимает функцию обратного вызова и Вам ничего не остаётся кроме того, чтобы обрабатывать данные асинхронно в колбеке. В JS это очень распространенный паттерн. Либо ищите аналог `con.query()`, который возвращает данные...либо подумайте над тем, тот ли стек технологий Вы выбрали, поскольку само устройство языка JavaScript, вынуждает постоянно использовать колбеки. В JavaScript Вам от них не убежать и Вам придётся так или иначе с ними работать.

Comment: @НикитаПетров, к анонимным функциям вы можете обращаться как к переменным, если Вы предварительно сохраните на них ссылку.Например: сначала "сохраняете функцию в переменную": `var test=function(){alert('test');}; `, а потом вызываете её: `test();`.Однако в данном случае обращение к анонимной функции Вам также не поможет, потому что вызываете её не Вы.

Comment: @НикитаПетров, насколько помню в JavaScript функция также является объектом. Именно поэтому Вы можете сохранять на них ссылки в переменных и потом вызывать их.

Comment: Спасибо, в java попроще с этим

Comment: @НикитаПетров, да. Но кому то нравится. На вкус и цвет, как говорится, все фломастеры разные. А если про фронтенд говорить, то ни у кого и выбора нет :)) . В любом случае изучение другого языка с философией, отличной от того что ты знал ранее, обогатит твой внутренний мир и расширит кругозор :-) Ну и с лямбдами в джаве и со scala впоследствии попроще будет :-)

Comment: @МихаилРебров справедливости ради сейчас есть «сахар» в виде async/await и промизов, так что можно писать **как бы** без колбеков.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, не знал. Спасибо.